# Get SUCCEEDED status from getContentModeration, AWS Rekognition

Tags: node.js, amazon-rekognition

Please, help me

I try to do video moderation with Amazon Rekognition.
I use startContentModeration method.
I get a result from getContentModeration but status is still IN_PROGRESS

How can I wait to get SUCCEEDED status?

```
    aws.Rekognition.getContentModeration({ JobId }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(data); // JobStatus: 'IN_PROGRESS',
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the process complete by AWS, the response should be one of them:

```
"IN_PROGRESS"|"SUCCEEDED"|"FAILED"
```